# Apache spark Transformation - split line and create it's combination

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark RDD as below.

```
abc,def,ghi

sdfdf,sdfsdf,dfdf444sdsdd
```

I want to transform every record (line) by splitting it with comma(,) to create all distinct combination of 2 spitted values.

Output RDD (eg) is below

```
abc def

abc ghi

def ghi
```

Comment: I tried below but it's not working.

Comment: val y = testA.map(x =>{
            
                
                var abd = x.split(",")
               if(abd.length > 1)
                {
                    
                    for(n <- 0 to (abd.length - 1))
                    {

                        
                        for(g <- n+1 until abd.length)
                        {
                            (abd(0) + abd(0))
                        }
 
                    }
                
                }
                else
                {
                    ""
                }
            }
)

Answer (score 1):

flatMap must be used for the combinations part.  Use something like the following:

```
rdd.map(_.split(",")).flatMap(tokens => getCombinations(tokens))
```

...where getCombinations has the signature:

```
def getCombinations(tokens: List[String]): List[(String, String)]
```